With Azure Durable functions how can you handle the Activity Function potentially being called multiple times?
All the documentation states an Activity Function should be Idempotent, but I can't find any examples of how to actually make that happen.
Even this example for the Fan Out Fan In function looks problematic, and does nothing to handle the potential for the activity function being called twice. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-cloud-backup?tabs=csharp
If you look at the CopyFileToBlob function, the best possible outcome for their example code would be the file getting copied twice which would mean getting billed for the code running twice. However, the more likely outcome is the second call would return an error, since the destination file is locked by the first instance.
My only thought for handling this would be testing for an instance of the same arguments already running, but then you need to return the Task from the first call and I can't think of any way to do that.
So how are we meant to ensure the activity function only runs once if it is called more than once?

The Orchestrator state keeps track of which activities it's called; crucially, including which parameters they were called with. When the Orchestrator resumes after awaiting an activity, it knows not to replay the ones that have already happened. I guess the Idempotency point is that it's therefore unlikely that an Orchestrator instance will re-run an activity, but it's technically possible, e.g. if the state information is deleted. Just prompting some other thoughts from people, because I think it might be a good question.

Summary
In normal operation, the Durable Functions (DF) infrastructure will guarantee that your Activity is only called once. In other words, it implements idempotency automatically, meaning you don't have to.
However. If the Function App runtime terminates abnormally during an Activity, then DF will attempt to re-start that Activity again with the same parameters. This is part of the "at least once" principle in DF. You have the flexibility to design how you recover after a fault.
We can validate this behaviour locally.
For the questioner's fan-in fan-out code example:

If the runtime is terminated mid-Activity, it will be subsequently re-started and the Blob will indeed be written twice.
If the Activity just exits normally or throws an exception, the Blob won't be written twice.
The method of idempotency protection always depends on use-case. For the Blob example, we could check if there's an existing (and complete) Blob, and exit if there is.

A minimum reproducible example
I find it helpful to understand the bounds of a problem when thinking about the mitigation. So with that in mind, I tested the fault conditions as follows:
Setup
Follow the quickstart for creating a Durable Function project: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-isolated-create-first-csharp?pivots=code-editor-vscode
Let's pretend it's a use-case where idempotency is important. So instead of saying "hello" to a city, let's imagine we're creating invoices for a customer. We must only invoice each customer once!
public class IdempotencyTest()
{
    [Function(nameof(IdempotencyTestOrchestrator))]
    public async Task IdempotencyTestOrchestrator(
        [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
    {
        ILogger logger = context.CreateReplaySafeLogger(nameof(IdempotencyTest));

        logger.LogWarning("Starting invoicing.");

        await Task.WhenAll([
            context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(InvoiceCustomer), "Contoso"),
            context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(InvoiceCustomer), "Acme"),
            context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(InvoiceCustomer), "Megadodo")
        ]);

        logger.LogWarning("Finished invoicing.");
    }

    [Function(nameof(InvoiceCustomer))]
    public async Task InvoiceCustomer(
        [ActivityTrigger] string name,
        FunctionContext executionContext)
    {
        ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger("InvoiceCustomer");

        logger.LogWarning("Invoicing {name}...", name);

        // Pretend an invoice gets generated.

        logger.LogWarning("Flagging {name} as invoiced", name);
    }
}

Running this in the local emulator, the output from the above logging is:
[2024-09-30T18:47:21.226Z] Starting invoicing.
[2024-09-30T18:47:21.370Z] Invoicing Contoso...
[2024-09-30T18:47:21.380Z] Flagging Contoso as invoiced
[2024-09-30T18:47:21.388Z] Invoicing Megadodo...
[2024-09-30T18:47:21.394Z] Invoicing Acme...
[2024-09-30T18:47:21.399Z] Flagging Acme as invoiced
[2024-09-30T18:47:21.400Z] Flagging Megadodo as invoiced
[2024-09-30T18:47:21.487Z] Finished invoicing.

The order of the output might change - that's not important here - but note that each log event only occurs once.
Replicating a runtime termination
This is pretty hard to replicate, but one way is to make the Activity hang for a long time. Like this:
[Function(nameof(InvoiceCustomer))]
public async Task InvoiceCustomer([ActivityTrigger] string name, FunctionContext executionContext)
{
    ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger("InvoiceCustomer");

    logger.LogWarning("Invoicing {name}...", name);

    if (name == "Acme")
    {
        // This will cause the runtime to terminate
        // while handling the "Acme" customer.
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromHours(10));
    }

    logger.LogWarning("Flagging {name} as invoiced", name);
}

I don't want to spend an hour waiting for this to crash. So instead, we'll edit our host.json file to reduce the functionTimeout to 30 seconds:
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    }
  },
  "functionTimeout": "00:00:30",
  "extensions": {
    "durableTask": {
      "storageProvider": {
        "type": "AzureStorage"
      }
    }
  }
}

Run the application again. After 30 seconds, the runtime is terminated, and the log is this:
[2024-09-30T19:06:00.168Z] Starting invoicing.
[2024-09-30T19:06:00.299Z] Invoicing Contoso...
[2024-09-30T19:06:00.303Z] Flagging Contoso as invoiced
[2024-09-30T19:06:00.319Z] Invoicing Acme...
[2024-09-30T19:06:00.326Z] Invoicing Megadodo...
[2024-09-30T19:06:00.332Z] Flagging Megadodo as invoiced

[2024-09-30T19:06:30.324Z] Timeout value of 00:00:30 exceeded by function 'Functions.InvoiceCustomer' (Id: '6fac3ae7-dccb-4cb0-97ee-9fff31b404ed'). Initiating cancellation.

[2024-09-30T19:06:30.344Z] Executed 'Functions.InvoiceCustomer' (Failed, Id=6fac3ae7-dccb-4cb0-97ee-9fff31b404ed, Duration=30032ms)

[2024-09-30T19:06:30.345Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Timeout value of 00:00:30 was exceeded by function: Functions.InvoiceCustomer.

[2024-09-30T19:06:32.368Z] A function timeout has occurred. Restarting worker process executing invocationId '6fac3ae7-dccb-4cb0-97ee-9fff31b404ed'

Note: the log says "Invoicing Acme..." which means we have now created an Acme invoice. We must not do this again.
Idempotency fail
Normally, when a Durable Orchestration awaits and then resumes (called a "Replay"^1), the DF framework keeps a history of which Activities have already run. You don't need to worry about idempotency because the DF history stops it running the same Activity again. Even if your Activity has thrown an exception that you've caught in the Orchestration.
But, when the runtime terminates while executing an Activity, the history won't have a record of it completing.
If you now re-launch the Durable Function App, without even triggering a new Orchestration, it starts checking its history and realises the Activity is missing. It then does something pretty smart: it launches that Activity again automatically.
This guarantees that your Activity will execute at least once - with the downside that it can run more than once. Here's the log:
[2024-09-30T19:15:20.866Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        IdempotencyTest_HttpStart: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/IdempotencyTest_HttpStart

        IdempotencyTestOrchestrator: orchestrationTrigger

        InvoiceCustomer: activityTrigger

[2024-09-30T19:15:21.385Z] Executing 'Functions.InvoiceCustomer' (Reason='(null)', Id=ed6dcea6-14d9-470a-95f0-3baef3dc4a85)
[2024-09-30T19:15:21.530Z] Invoicing Acme...

This is the problem. We had already created the Acme invoice, before it crashed. Now we're creating another one.
Our logic needs to be re-written so that it's idempotent. Otherwise our customer gets invoiced twice. The method of idempotency always depends on use-case, but an example here might be:
[Function(nameof(InvoiceCustomer))]
public async Task InvoiceCustomer([ActivityTrigger] string name, FunctionContext executionContext)
{
    // Probably also wrap this whole
    // method in a Unit Of Work pattern...
    using var someUnitOfWork = _uowFactory.CreateUow();

    ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger("InvoiceCustomer");

    if (await _myInvoiceService.InvoiceExistsFor(name))
    {
        // Quick exit.
        logger.LogWarning("Invoice already exists for {name}", name);
        return;
    }

    // Actually create the invoice.
    // Likely have some contraint in the repo and UOW
    // to avoid a race condition.
    logger.LogInformation("Invoicing {name}...", name);
    await _myInvoiceService.CreateInvoiceForCustomer(name);

    // Mark it as Invoiced.
    logger.LogInformation("Flagging {name} as invoiced", name);
    await _myInvoiceService.FlagCustomerAsInvoiced(name);

    // NB this is just to illustrate; likely all the above
    // operations would be best done in the same service method.
}

When would this be a problem?
Only if something causes the Function runtime to completely terminate. This is a serious fault; not just any old exception being thrown.
It means something abnormal like the Function exceeding its maximum runtime, or running out of memory, or exhausting the Socket pool. The kind of fault that you might be familiar with causing a 503 response in an HTTP endpoint.
Further reading

"Durable Functions: Semantics for Stateful Services" https://doi.org/10.1145/3485510

Final thoughts: being pragmatic
I'm straying towards opinion here, so don't take this absolutely.

There are lots of ways an application can fail to meet idempotency principles. For example, if you haven't bothered making your API endpoint calls idempotent, then that's a more likely risk than your Durable Activities are anyway.

You might not need to make your code idempotent if you have mitigations that protect against the effect of something running twice. One example is having a UNIQUE constraint in a SQL table, which will prevent you executing a CREATE operation twice for the same value. You haven't consciously made your code idempotent, but your repository won't let it be persisted anyway. NB your mileage may vary - don't just assume everything is OK because you're using SQL constraints!

Ultimately, needing to consider idempotency isn't just a Durable Functions constraint. It's something that needs considering across all parts of a system and implementing where necessary.



Thanks for the thorough explanation, and sorry for the delayed response!

Thanks, it was an excellent question! A nice one to research and experiment with.
